# Using varchar(MAX) vs TEXT on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, text, varchar, sql-types

I just read that the `VARCHAR(MAX)` datatype (which can store close to 2GB of char data) is the recommended replacement for the `TEXT` datatype in SQL Server 2005 and Next SQL SERVER versions.

If I want to search inside a column for any string, which operation is quicker?

1. Using a the `LIKE` clause against a `VARCHAR(MAX)` column?

   `WHERE COL1 LIKE '%search string%'`
2. Using the `TEXT` column and put a *Full Text Index*/*Catalog* on this column, and then search using the `CONTAINS` clause?

   `WHERE CONTAINS (Col1, 'MyToken')`

Comment: This post is also helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564755/sql-server-text-type-v-s-varchar-data-type

Comment: The most important mention in that post is a link to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) showing that `TEXT` and `NTEXT` (and `IMAGE`) are deprecated.

Comment: Look at the link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28980502/1805776

Comment: Note that TEXT is being deprecated, if you have the choice, do not use TEXT. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65625298/when-will-ntext-text-and-image-be-deprecated

Answer (score 354, accepted):

The `VARCHAR(MAX)` type is a replacement for `TEXT`. The basic difference is that a `TEXT` type will always store the data in a blob whereas the `VARCHAR(MAX)` type will attempt to store the data directly in the row unless it exceeds the 8k limitation and at that point it stores it in a blob.

Using the LIKE statement is identical between the two datatypes. The additional functionality `VARCHAR(MAX)` gives you is that it is also can be used with `=` and `GROUP BY` as any other `VARCHAR` column can be. However, if you do have a lot of data you will have a huge performance issue using these methods.

In regard to if you should use `LIKE` to search, or if you should use *Full Text Indexing* and `CONTAINS`. This question is the same regardless of `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `TEXT`.

If you are searching large amounts of text and performance is key then you should use a *Full Text Index*.

`LIKE` is simpler to implement and is often suitable for small amounts of data, but it has extremely poor performance with large data due to its inability to use an index.

Comment: I didn't know that it would store in the page at 8k, and out of the page if larger.  Very cool.

Comment: Your last line is partially wrong. LIKE can not use index ONLY if wildcard is at the beginning of the string being searched against.

Comment: Is it no problem to alter a field from a text to a varchar(max) from an existing table with data?

Comment: I cannot find any discription about "varchar exceeds 8k will be stored in blob" from official docs，could you give a link about this?

Answer (score 19):

For large text, the *full text index* is *much* faster.  But you can *full text index* `varchar(max)`as well.

Answer (score 19):

- **Basic Definition**

`TEXT` and `VarChar(MAX)` are non-Unicode large variable length character data type, which can store maximum of 2,147,483,647 non-Unicode characters (i.e. maximum storage capacity is: 2GB).

- **Which one to Use?**

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187993.aspx), Microsoft is suggesting to avoid using the `TEXT` datatype and it will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. `VarChar(MAX)` is the suggested data type for storing large string values instead of the `TEXT` data type.

- **In-Row or Out-of-Row Storage**

Data of a `TEXT` type column is stored out-of-row in a separate LOB data pages. The row in the table data page will only have a 16 byte pointer to the LOB data page where the actual data is present. The data of a `VarChar(MAX)` type column is stored in-row if it is less than or equal to 8000 bytes. If the value of a `VarChar(MAX)` column is greater than 8000 bytes, then the `VarChar(MAX)` column value is stored in a separate LOB data pages and row will only have a 16 byte pointer to the LOB data page where the actual data is present. So "in-row" `VarChar(MAX)` is good for searches and retrieval.

- **Supported/Unsupported Functionalities**

Some string functions, operators and constructs don't work on a `TEXT` type column, but they do work on a `VarChar(MAX)` type column.

1. `=` Equal to operator on `VarChar(MAX)` type column
2. `GROUP BY` clause on `VarChar(MAX)` type column

- **System IO Considerations**

As we know, the `VarChar(MAX)` type column values are stored out-of-row only when the length of the value is greater than 8000 bytes or there is not enough space in the row, otherwise it will store it in-row. So if most of the values stored in the `VarChar(MAX)` column are large and stored out-of-row, the data retrieval behavior will almost similar to a `TEXT` type column.

If most of the values stored in `VarChar(MAX)` type columns are small enough to store in-row, then retrieval of data where LOB columns are not included requires more data pages to be read, since the LOB column value is stored in-row in the same data page where the non-LOB column values are stored. But if the `SELECT` query includes a LOB column, then it requires less pages to be read for the data retrieval compared to the `TEXT` type columns.

**Conclusion**

Use `VarChar(MAX)` data type rather than `TEXT` for better performance.

[Source](http://sqlhints.com/2016/05/11/differences-between-sql-server-text-and-varcharmax-data-type/)

Answer (score 17):

You can't search a text field without converting it from text to varchar.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (a text)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('a')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('a')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('b')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('c')
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('d')


SELECT *
FROM @table
WHERE a = 'a'
```

This will give you the error:

> The data types `text` and `varchar` are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Whereas this does not:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (a varchar(max))
```

Interestingly, `LIKE` still works, i.e.

```
WHERE a LIKE '%a%'
```

Answer (score 6):

If using *MS Access* (especially older versions like 2003) you are forced to use `TEXT` datatype on SQL Server as MS Access does not recognize `nvarchar(MAX)` as a Memo field in Access, whereas `TEXT` is recognized as a Memo-field.