# Is a nvarchar(max) less performant than a nvarchar(100) for instance?

Tags: sql-server

Is a nvarchar(max) less performant than a nvarchar(100) for instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same question was answered [here (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148398/are-there-any-disadvantages-to-always-using-nvarcharmax) and [here (MSDN)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/4d9c6504-496e-45ba-a7a3-ed5bed731fcc)

Quoting [David Kreps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148398/are-there-any-disadvantages-to-always-using-nvarcharmax/148465#148465)'s answer:

> When you store data to a VARCHAR(N) column, the values are physically stored in the same way. But when you store it to a VARCHAR(MAX) column, behind the screen the data is handled as a TEXT value. So there is some additional processing needed when dealing with a VARCHAR(MAX) value. (only if the size exceeds 8000)
>
> VARCHAR(MAX) or NVARCHAR(MAX) is considered as a 'large value type'. Large value types are usually stored 'out of  row'. It means that the data row will have a pointer to another location where the 'large value' is stored...

Answer (score 5):

Note that in addition to [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460598/is-a-nvarcharmax-less-performant-than-a-nvarchar100-for-instance/2460631#2460631) you cannot index an `nvarchar(max)` column, so in that circumstance it can be a limitation in terms of performance.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is to use the data type that most suits the data you are storing in it. If you're talking about a varchar(100) then it sounds unlikely you will need to store data as large as a varchar(max) can handle and should probably stick with a varchar(100)

The questions to ask yourself are what data are you storing, how often are you storing and retriving it. How are you using it, lookups, searching or storage only?

As for the differences, varchar(max) is NOT equivalent to TEXT. The main enhancement in varchar(max) is that the data IS still stored in the row unless is exceeds the max length of 8k at which point is is stored in a blob.

See this question that is more specific about the differences between varchar(max) and text.

[Using varchar(MAX) vs TEXT on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834788/ms-sql-server-varcharmax-vs-text/)

Comment: When the size of the data in a varchar(max) exceeds the max length, sql stores it in a blob.  Does this imply that you will likely get table fragmentation as a result of this hidden process?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When comparing a variable or column of type MAX the internal code uses stream semantics. The variables types of length less than 8000 use direct comparison semantics. A simple example:

```
create table A (k int, x varchar(8000));
create clustered index cdxA on A(k);
go

insert into A (k, x) select number, name from master..spt_values;
go

declare @s datetime = getutcdate(),
  @i int = 0;

set nocount on;
while(@i < 100000)
begin
  declare @x varchar(8000);
  select @x = x from A where k = 1 and x = 'rpc';
  set @i = @i + 1;
end

select datediff(ms, @s, getutcdate());
```

Running this repeatedly yields measured loop times of 2786, 2746, 2746, 2900, 2623, 2736, so an avg of around 2.7s.

The very same code, but replaced the two occurences of varchar(8000) with varchar(max) yields measured times of 4916, 5203, 5280, 5040, 5543, 5130, an average time of 5.2s significantly higher than the non-max type.

Conclusion is that in very tight loops the varchar(max) is slower in comparing and assigning when compared with the non-max types. Like all optimizations, it should be only considered and applied after careful measurement reveals that it is a bottleneck.

Note that the difference is visible **even on a data of actual length 3 chars**, and is not derived from differences in storage.