# what is the diff between TEXT and VARCHAR datafields?

Tags: text, types, varchar

I have following confusions -
1. Which datatype is used for bigger amount of data store
2. When we specify varcha(100) so this 100 represent `100 characters` or `100 bits or bytes`

Comment: As you see from the answers, this depends a lot on which database server you're using - e.g. mySQL's VARCHAR is very different from MSSQL's varchar

Answer (score 4):

On SQL Server

varchar(100) =  100 ascii characters and 102 bytes

nvarchar(100) =  100 unicode/ascii characters and 202 bytes of storage

text and ntext go up to 2GB but are deprecated (from sql server 2005), you should use varchar(max) and nvarchar(max) which both also go up to 2 GB instead

Comment: The storage requirements are not 100 bytes for the `VARCHAR(100)`, but 102 bytes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx. Same goes for `NVARCHAR`.

Comment: Yes I know 2 bytes are used to denote start and end position, this is also why you use char(2) not varchar(2). Thanks, updated the answer

Comment: Actually no, the 2 bytes are used to store the size of the `VARCHAR` array and not as a start-end position. And you don't use `CHAR` rather than `VARCHAR` if the columns differ significantly in size, as this will be a waste of space compared to `VARCHAR`.

Comment: If you have more than 1 varchar column then there is also a 2-byte overhead per row to maintain the 
count of variable columns. I gave a char(2) vs varchar(2) example not char(50) vs varchar(50) because of course in that case if you only use 25 bytes you would want to use varchar

Answer (score 2):

TEXT will store up to 64K - MySQL (for example) provides variants as well: TINYTEXT (256 bytes), MEDIUMTEXT (16MB) and LONGTEXT (4GB).

A VARCHAR(100) column will hold up to 100 characters of text.  You can use a VARBINARY for binary data, in which case a VARBINARY(100) field will hold up to 100 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

If using `MySQL` the difference is mainly related to the [storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html):

- `VARCHAR`: `L + 1` bytes if column values require 0 – 255 bytes, `L + 2` bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes
- `TEXT`: `L + 2` bytes, where `L < 2^16`

where `L` is the actual size of the entry

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about MS SQL Server:

1) `varchar(max)`: `varchar(max)` is a replacement for TEXT

2) `varchar(100)` = 100 characters (single byte ascii chars)

(whereas `nvarchar(100)` = 100 characters (double byte unicode chars))

Ref: [char and varchar (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)

[Just found a possible duplicate: [ms sql server; varchar(MAX) vs TEXT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834788/ms-sql-server-varcharmax-vs-text) ]

Answer (score 0):

The datatype TEXT is limited to 4000 characters where in the new data type Varchar(max) is meant to store Maximum Length of characters or the length that you specified

For more information check this

http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/char_string.htm