# Converting Text to varchar(MAX)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ado.net

I'm working currently on a SQL Server project that has been built for SQL Server 2000. In some tables of this project, the `Text` Datatype was used. Because have to do some bigger changes on this database(s), it would be a good occasion to change these fields to `VARCHAR(MAX)`. All SQL Servers are now 2005 and 2008.

Are there any problems to be expected when I change all the `Text` datatypes to `VARCHAR(MAX)` or are all features that are supported by the `Text` datatype also supported by `VARHCHAR(MAX)`.

As an additional information, the data from the database is queried mostly from a .net application, besides this, also excel, access and some statistical tools access the database directly via odbc/ole-db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check answer from: [Using varchar(MAX) vs TEXT on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834788/ms-sql-server-varcharmax-vs-text)