# Issue After Converting Table Column From "Text" to Varchar(max)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, text, varchar

I had a table called Person with column PersonDescription which was of type "text".
I had issues with updating this column so i ran the script

> ALTER TABLE dbo.Person ALTER COLUMN
>   PersonDescription VARCHAR(max)

to change the column to be 
varchar(max). This was all fine and ran instantly. However now i have noticed that anytime i try to update this column then It is taking up to 3-4 mins to execute. Query is

> Update Person set PersonDescription
>   ='persons description' where personid=18

After this update is ran then it executes instantly. This is all fine but when this change goes to production then this table has a million records so every person that logs in is going to timeout when this runs. Can anyone tell me how i can prevent this. Is there another script etc that i need to run. After running the update i saw that Statman runs on sqlserver which is what is taking the time.

thanks
Niall

Comment: If it is auto creating statistics that should only be a one off task. Not sure what happens if a timeout happens while it is compiling the query though. That query seems like it shouldn't need any stats on the `PersonDescription` column though. Only on `personid`

Comment: thanks for replying Martin. i managed to fix this by creating a deployment script which updates the new modified column for 1 single record. this way the stats get updated before first user logs into the system so wont cause any un wanted issues. thanks.

Comment: I wonder if this could be related to a bug we discovered in sql server when we changed text to varchar(max) on fields that were previously null. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295771/why-is-is-not-null-returning-null-values-for-a-varcharmax-in-sql-server. We fixed it using sql like UPDATE Person SET PersonDescription = PersonDescription

Comment: I would love an answer on this. the internet is void and I have a table with 100 million rows I *need* to convert.

Comment: Although nothing official, there is this (which was posted a day after this so maybe same person asking?): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac799621-56cf-4a47-a7bc-2eb4b1cf2aba/convert-text-to-varcharmax

Answer (score 0):

It is my opinion that the issue is due to SQL server calculating if it should store the data in a blob or the row.

See:[Using varchar(MAX) vs TEXT on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834788/using-varcharmax-vs-text-on-sql-server)

"The VARCHAR(MAX) type is a replacement for TEXT. The basic difference is that a TEXT type will always store the data in a blob whereas the VARCHAR(MAX) type will attempt to store the data directly in the row unless it exceeds the 8k limitation and at that point it stores it in a blob."

Are also you using a full-text index?  Disable indexes, update, rebuild indexes.

Have you tried creating a new table and copying records to it?  Do you still have the same performance issues?