# SQL 2008 - varchar(max) vs text data types

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, varchar, sqldatatypes, varcharmax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server Text type vs. varchar data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564755/sql-server-text-type-vs-varchar-data-type)
>   [Using varchar(MAX) vs TEXT on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834788/using-varcharmax-vs-text-on-sql-server)

from this article, it looks like they both have the same size capacity: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

is that truly correct? what are the real differences?

i just migrated some data from oracle (clob and made it into a varchar(max), but it looks like it truncated some of the values anyway, should i use TEXT instead?

Thank you!

Comment: TEXT is becoming depracated - http://andrewm-developmentnotes.blogspot.com/2011/03/text-type-deprecated-in-sql-server-2008.html

Comment: This thread has the answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564755/sql-server-text-type-vs-varchar-data-type

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834788/using-varcharmax-vs-text-on-sql-server

Comment: what code did you use to migrate the data? I think you have a problme with how you did it not what the datatype was.

Comment: Look at the link http://stackoverflow.com/q/28980502/1805776

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you should not use `TEXT`. For one, [it has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), and also you will find that many string operations do not work against it. Do not use `TEXT`, `NTEXT` or `IMAGE` at all - use `VARCHAR(MAX)`, `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead.

Comment: Damn Microsoft. Why can't they stick to conventions and use text like MySQL and Postgres?

Comment: @Henley because they used text already and it sucked. Why couldn't MySQL follow the standard and use offset/fetch instead of this silly limit crap? Mud flies both ways...

Comment: not if there's a lot of wind

Answer (score 9):

The legacy types (TEXT, NTEXT, IMAGE) are deprecated and support for them will be dropped in a future version of SQL Server.

There are significant differences in how you use them. The new MAX types support efficient updates with the [`.WRITE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) syntax. The legacy types have an arcane set of functions to achieve the same ([`TEXTPTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176068.aspx), [`UPDATETEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189466.aspx), [`sp_invalidate_testptr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189468.aspx)).

The new MAX types can be used in functions like [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) or [`SUBSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx), any function that accepts a `VARCHAR(N)` will also accept a `VARCHAR(MAX)`.

The legacy types do not support implicit conversion which the MAX types support, see [Data Type Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Certain engine features work with MAX types, but not with the legacy ones, eg. online operations (in [SQL 11 they support tables with BLOBs](http://rusanu.com/2011/08/05/online-index-operations-for-indexes-containing-lob-columns/))

Answer (score 2):

The linked article only deals with space allocation. At a minimum, know that [text, ntext and image data types will be removed from future releases of SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) so for new tables, use varchar(max), nvarchar(max) or varbinary(max).

Of equal importance would be *how* one interacts with those values. Would you rather use the standard column = 'really long value' or [UPDATETEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189466.aspx) and other less common operations to work on a column because of the data type?