# varchar(max) vs nvarchar(max) vs text in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, rdbms

In MYSQL, Is there any difference in the performance of select queries on table having 10 millions of records, when we do not give right data type for the columns?

For example, If we use TEXT as data type for column which doesn't really store so much of data. when we reduce this column to have varchar(max) as datatype, will the performance increases?

Which is best practice to use either TEXT or varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) mainly for performance on table?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834788/using-varcharmax-vs-text-on-sql-server

Comment: Clearly, of those options, `TEXT` would be best because `varchar(max)` and `nvarchar(max)` would result in syntax errors.

Comment: Short answer is - no, you will get no performance gain whatsoever. At best, we might be talking nanoseconds, if that.