# How to select text datatype in SQL Server faster

Tags: sql-server, database, optimization, sql-server-2012

I have a column with `TEXT` datatype that needs to store huge amounts of text so I have to use the `TEXT` datatype.

But this column need to be frequently searched. What should I do if I want that search faster than before?

This is my query (max `DATALENGTH` for column `workDescription` are 399721)

```
SELECT [workID],
       [staffID],
       [workDate],
       [startTime],
       [endTime],
       [projectID],
       [timeFor],
       [workType],
       [workTitle],
       [workDescription], ---> text datatype
       [isDeleted],
       [createdDate],
       [createdBy],
       [lastUpdate],
       [updatedBy]
FROM [IndosoftDb_LIVE].[dbo].[tblTimesheet]
WHERE [workDescription] LIKE '%event%'
    OR [workTitle] LIKE '%event%'
```

Note : my PM doesn't want to change it to `VARCHAR(MAX)`. He was afraid that data is truncated.

Comment: [`varchar(max)` is the replacement for `text`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834788/using-varcharmax-vs-text-on-sql-server), so your PM's fears are unfounded. Why is he making technical decisions for the project?

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/

Comment: What @Hackerman said.  You should check out Full Text Search.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> so i have to use TEXT datatype

Wrong, you don't - `varchar(max)` will suit just fine. Don't forget, `text`, `ntext` and `image` data types became deprecated back in 2005. That, and access to their contents via SQL is rather cumbersome, comparing to their `(max)` successors.

Your PM is incompetent in this particular question, and his suspicions are easy to refute - just open the documentation for the `varchar(max)` data type.

To answer your question - full-text index might help (the actual improvement will depend on your exact search patterns). But I must warn you - the thing has a rather steep learning curve, and can prove difficult to master.

Comment: i try to use full text index but the result is not the same
so there just 1 solution that is to convert that with varchar(max)?

Comment: FTS differs from `like` in search capabilities and (sometimes) results. Most probably you will have to rewrite all search queries if you will go to use it. The column datatype does not affect it, however - you can still use `text` if you want.