# STUFF() does not support TEXT datatype?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm using the following snippet:

```
SELECT ID, abc = STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + name
        FROM temp1 As T2
        WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
    ).value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
, 1, 1, '')
```

But the result is longer than 4000 chars (`varchar(max)`), so I tried to replace this with `text` to support longer strings. But then I get an error `data type TEXT used in VALUE method is invalid`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `varchar(max)` can contain a lot more than just 4000 characters (and `text` has been deprecated for ages)

Comment: `varchar` can be declared up for a `varchar(8000)` before you need to use `MAX` (`nvarchar` is 4000).

Comment: Whatever problem you're having with string truncation (and there may be one, related to how Management Studio or your client process the result) the use of `varchar(max)` isn't the cause of it, and `text` is not the solution.

Comment: ON a different note, `STUF` is more than happy to accept a value longer than 4000, or even 8000. Try: `SELECT LEN(STUFF(CONVERT(varchar(MAX),REPLICATE('A',8000)) + CONVERT(varchar(MAX),REPLICATE('B',8000)),1,1,''));` The returned value is 15999, so `STUFF` was quite happily able to return more than 8000 characters (note that `REPLICATE` cannot return more than 8000 characters, and hence why the query is written the way it is).

Comment: [Using varchar(MAX) vs TEXT on SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834788/using-varcharmax-vs-text-on-sql-server)

Comment: In case the comment it isn't clear, `varchar(MAX)` can contain up to 2 billion characters. No need to use text.

Comment: I don't understand -- I actually have exactly that in my query (`varchar(max)`) but when I do a `len()` on the output, I find many records truncated at 8000 chars

Comment: Datatypes Text, NText and Image have been deprecated since SQL Server 2008. Today, 10 years and 5 versions later (not counting Azure) I would expect them to die already, but unfortunately Microsoft still keeps them around for some reason.

Comment: `'(./text())[1]'` -> `'.'` and show your code with `len()`

Comment: Stuff supports well over 8000 chars, [as demonstrated here.](https://rextester.com/ERCQO67515)

Comment: Check out Martin Smith's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18483/varcharmax-field-cutting-off-data-after-8000-characters) to a similar question over at dba.StackExchange.Com. This might be the key to why your strings are truncated.

Comment: @Larnu replicate is more than happy to return a value longer than 8000 chars, as long as it's input string is [n]varchar(max) - try `DECLARE @T varchar(max) = 'a'
SELECT LEN(REPLICATE(@T, 12345))`

Comment: @ZoharPeled you're right. Must had misread the caveat.