# When will ntext, text, and image be deprecated?

Tags: azure-sql-database, data-migration

We are currently migrating from SQL Server to Azure SQL and the DMA Data Migration Assistant has flagged up a large number of tables that are using TEXT fields.

Ntext, text, and image be deprecated [in future versions of SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?) but the docs do not say when.

If we ignore this warning and migrate to Azure SQL with TEXT fields intact with the aim of migrating TEXT to VARCHAR over time, would there be any immediate downsides?

Presumably we would be given warning if Azure SQL was to stop working with TEXT fields at some point in the future?

Comment: The time is not sure, just for now, we still can create these data types. I think it's in progress .

Comment: Hi Marcus, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Small note: The types are already "deprecated".  We just have not removed them from the product yet.  Please move off them to the other types.  The newer types are faster, support more capabilities, and you should not plan on continuing to use deprecated features whenever you can move off them.  (We deprecated these in SQL 2005, so it's time to move off ;)).

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT thanks.  Is there an eta for removal?

Comment: We don't try to remove things unless we truly need to do so.  However, you should assume that we could do it at any time.  I see no reason anyone should be using the old types at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These datatypes were actually deprecated back in SQL2005. The important thing is to understand is what MS means by deprecated - it does not mean "imminent removal" or "will not work". Deprecation means:

- The feature is in maintenance mode only. No new changes will be done, including those related to addressing inter-operability with new features.
- We (MS) strive not to remove a deprecated feature from future releases to make upgrades easier. However, under rare situations, we may choose to permanently discontinue (remove) the feature from SQL Server if it limits future innovations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15

Whilst best practice would be to change existing column definitions to a supported datatype and certainly not to use them in new dev, it's worth pointing out that you can find TEXT, NTEXT & IMAGE columns in the SSRS system databases so I don't think there's any need to rush into anything. As the documentation says: "we strive not to remove deprecated features...(except) under rare situations". If these deprecated data types have been hanging around since SQL2005 I think it's fair to say MS aren't prioritising their actual removal.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know the exact date when the new version SQL Server published, no official document talked about this, but I think it's in progress. When the product team finishing the test, they will publish it.

Just for now, we still can create these data types in Azure SQL database:
[image]

You should follow the suggestions that use `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar` instead to avoid the error which may happens in future.

In one word, these four data types will be removed in the next version of SQL Server. But in current and previous versions, they are still supported.

As I understand, the warning is to remind you:

1. When you develop with the new/next version SQL Server/Azure SQL,
   please use `varchar` or `nvarchar` instead of these for data types.
2. When migrate the data from old version to the new next version, pay
   attention to the data type mapping.

And we can't answer you if there be any immediate downsides when you "migrate to Azure SQL with TEXT fields intact with the aim of migrating TEXT to VARCHAR over time".  If you still insist to create the `text` in the new next version SQL Server, I think you will get the error message like "text is not supported in this version".

HTP.