# String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have met some problem with the SQL server, this is the function I created:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[testing1](@price int)
RETURNS @trackingItems1 TABLE (
   item       nvarchar  NULL,
   warehouse   nvarchar NULL,
   price int   NULL
) 
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @trackingItems1(item, warehouse, price)
   SELECT ta.item, ta.warehouse, ta.price 
   FROM   stock ta
   WHERE  ta.price >= @price; 

   RETURN;
END;
```

When I write a query to use that function like the following it getting the error

> *String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated*

How can I fix this problem?

```
select * from testing1(2)
```

This is the way I create the table

```
CREATE TABLE stock(item       nvarchar(50) NULL,
                   warehouse   nvarchar(50) NULL,
                   price int NULL);
```

Comment: It simply means that you are inserting a value that is greater than the maximum allowed value. Ex, a column can only hold up to 5 characters, but you are inserting 10-character string.

Comment: @JW but in my table there is included the value 2 for the price, and the data type is actually same (eg:int)

Comment: Also way of calling function is select [dbo].testing1(2) from tablename

Comment: @AshReva when i trying your suggestion, it get this error "Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.testing1", or the name is ambiguous." but i can confirm that i have this method in my table-valued function already

Comment: Can you include the schema definition for the stock table?

Comment: how can i thank everyone in one time? haha, i solved it tq, the problem is in my functions i didn declare nvarchar(50)

Comment: I got this error in a different context, altering a column from 11 to 4 characters.  The trick for me was to go through and update the data in the column first (in this case I wanted the RIGHT(column, 4)).  Then it happily let me reduce the column size.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server String or binary data would be truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388756/sql-server-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated)

Answer (score 74):

When you define [`varchar` etc without a length, the default is 1.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186939.aspx)

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified with the CAST function, the default length is 30.

So, if you expect 400 bytes in the `@trackingItems1` column from `stock`, use `nvarchar(400)`.

Otherwise, you are trying to fit >1 character into `nvarchar(1)` = fail

As a comment, this is [bad use of table value function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/510754/27535) too because it is "multi statement". It can be written like this and it will run better

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[testing1](@price int)
RETURNS
AS
   SELECT ta.item, ta.warehouse, ta.price 
   FROM   stock ta
   WHERE  ta.price >= @price;
```

Of course, you could just use a normal SELECT statement..

Answer (score 44):

The maximal length of the target column is shorter than the value you try to insert.

Rightclick the table in SQL manager and go to 'Design' to visualize your table structure and column definitions.

Edit:

Try to set a length on your nvarchar inserts thats the same or shorter than whats defined in your table.

Comment: for me the issue was with length of column, so changing from `nvarchar(50)` to `ntext` in sql sever, solves the issue, hope helps someone

Comment: @stom you should always try to use the smallest possible length for your data. Doing so keeps your tables as small and fast as possible, and shows intent as well. If someone need to index or migrate your db in a few years, they will have to find out why the tables is designed the way they are. That said, if you want "unlimited" text in a field, ntext is a viable solution.

Comment: thank you for the tip given on performance, right now i am storing website links and some are long , so i choose ntext.

Comment: @stom You could set it to nvarchar(2083) which is the max length for Internet Explorer. That way you maximize performance and compatibility.

Comment: ya `nvarchar(2083)`  is best column type for a URL from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159928/what-is-the-best-column-type-for-url), thank you.

Answer (score 24):

In my case, I was getting this error because my table had

```
varchar(50)
```

but I was injecting 67 character long string, which resulted in thi error. Changing it to

```
varchar(255)
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: :) Changing to varchar(some_value) fixed my problem.

Answer (score 8):

Specify a size for the *item* and *warehouse* like in the [dbo].[testing1] FUNCTION

```
@trackingItems1 TABLE (
item       nvarchar(25)  NULL, -- 25 OR equal size of your item column
warehouse   nvarchar(25) NULL, -- same as above
price int   NULL

)
```

Since in MSSQL only saying only *nvarchar* is equal to nvarchar(1) hence the values of the column from the *stock* table are truncated

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU6 and SQL Server 2017 CU12
introduced trace flag 460 in order to return the details of truncation warnings.
You can enable it at the query level or at the server level.

**Query level**

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST (ColumnTest)
VALUES (‘Test truncation warnings’)
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 460);
GO
```

**Server Level**

```
DBCC TRACEON(460, -1);
GO
```

From SQL Server 2019 you can enable it at database level:

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION 
SET VERBOSE_TRUNCATION_WARNINGS = ON;
```

The old output message is:

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 30, Line 13
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

The new output message is:

```
Msg 2628, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
String or binary data would be truncated in table 'DbTest.dbo.TEST', column 'ColumnTest'. Truncated value: ‘Test truncation warnings‘'.
```

In a future SQL Server 2019 release, message 2628 will replace message 8152 by default.