# where to put insert select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert, ssms

I have the following select statement and I want to input the results into my new table "additions" that I created. The select statement has the same columns in my new table

```
Select ThisWeek.* 
from
(
SELECT table1, table 2, table 3, getdate() as Date,
  FROM ...
  where ....)
  )ThisWeek
  left outer join
  (
  SELECT ...
  FROM .....
  where ..... ) LastWeek
  on .....
  where Lastweek... is null

  union

Select 
table1,table2
  getdate() as Date,
LastWeek.table1, lastweek.table2
(
SELECT...
  FROM ....
  ....
  FROM....)
  )ThisWeek
  Right outer join
  (
  SELECT table1, table 2 ....
  FROM ....
  where...
  FROM ....] ) - 2)
  ) LastWeek
  on ....
  where ... is null
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have created  **additions** table use **INSERT INTO**

```
INSERT INTO additions (column1, column2, column3, ...)
Select ThisWeek.* 
from(
.....
)
```

you can use **INTO** syntax to create **additions** table as follows:

```
Select ThisWeek.* 
INTO additions
from(
.....
)
```

Comment: thanks, i have created additions table but when i put it before first select statement i get the following error:   "String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: i cant add screenshot in these replies but in my first reply  to your comment i have copied and pasted the error message

Comment: it is mainly due to length of string in design tab  set data type of varchar to varchar(max) or nvarchar(max)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388756/sql-server-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019397/string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-the-statement-has-been-terminated