# What's the proper column type to save urls in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I've been using `varchar(300)`,but I've also noticed longer urls.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `TEXT`, it's enough for every `URL`.

Note that with long `URL`s, you won't be able to create an index that covers the whole `URL`. If you need a `UNIQUE` index, you should calculate the `URL` hash, store the hash separately and index the hash instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "it"? `TEXT` is a standard and supported feature, `MD5` hashing is too (and `MySQL` contains a function for calculating the hash).

Comment: That's how I do it, as well.  Also, it's worth considering benchmarking various hash functions, I chose MD5, since it's slightly faster than all the others, but MD4.

Comment: Seems there is no `MD4` in PHP.

Comment: @Nikola: `MySQL` lacks `MD4` supports, but if it did, it would certainly be a preferred hash function.

Comment: @Quassnoi, yes, you're right, but I don't hash in MySQL (it showed slower), YMMV.

@eugene y, hash is one of the columns in the table.

Comment: @unknown googler, yes it does, via Hash cryptography extension, do print_r(hash_algos()).

Answer (score 3):

Technically HTTP does not put a limit on the max length of a URL. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-url) SO post.

So `varchar` will not be of help, You'll have to use `TEXT`

Comment: The post you have referenced states that urls have a max length of 2048. How you state "Technically HTTP does not put a limit on the max length of a URL"?

Answer (score 2):

As of now:

<< MySQL 5.0.3 use **TEXT**

or

>= MySQL 5.0.3 use **VARCHAR(2083)**

[check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/219664/3048495)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html), browsers can handle different URL lengths (and very long). So you should consider using `text` as data type.