# How to speed up querying a TEXT field?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

I have a big table, and searching often happens by a `TEXT` field (it can't be `VARCHAR`). This is very slow; so, I tried to add an index:

```
ALTER TABLE big_table ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `Index_name` (`NAME`);
```

However, performance didn't change, still too slow. How can I add a "good" index? (it would be a plus if it could be unique)

Here's the DDL for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE  `bigtable` (
  `NAME` text NOT NULL,
  `VALUE` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DESCRIPTION` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and the explain:

```
explain 
 UPDATE table 
    SET VALUE = VALUE + 1, DESCRIPTION = "whatever" 
  where name = "Total visits";

id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key,  key_len, ref , rows,  Extra
1,  SIMPLE,      table, ALL,  null,          null, null,    null, 30592, Using Where
```

and after the index reading:

```
id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key,  key_len, ref , rows,  Extra
1,  SIMPLE, table, ALL, null, null, null, null, 30592, Using where
```

Comment: What kind of search? It seems you'll need `FULLTEXT`

Comment: What queries are you running? What are the explain plans?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Indexing a MySql TEXT column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889827/indexing-a-mysql-text-column)

Comment: not possible, I saw that thread too, and didnt help

Comment: Your proposed duplicate is about _how_ to index @James; the OP is asking how to speed it up.

Comment: Then your question is probably better suited on the [DBA website](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Can you show your query that you use to search by using full text index?

Comment: Just because something _might_ be on-topic on DBA does _not_ mean it's off-topic on SO. There are thousands of questions about database performance on SO.

Comment: the thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889827/indexing-a-mysql-text-column wont work, if there are duplicated rows

Comment: well, now the question is to set the optimal key length, the maximal length of text is 2151 now

Comment: ok, Im triing with "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON table (name(*));" but it drops "duplicate entry" or "the key is too long, max size is 1000"

Comment: Index prefix limit for MyISAM is 1000 bytes. But because you're using `utf8` the actual index length (which is the number of characters for non binary data types) is only 333. `CREATE INDEX idx_name IN bigtable (name(333));`.

Comment: Now do you always search for the complete string entry (like in your example `Total visits`) or you need to do partial (pattern) searches too (like 'total%')?

Comment: yes, always search the whole text. Anyway, I solved: added a field which contain this string in MD5 format, and searching goes through this