# Slow MYSQL query after using inner join and sub query

Tags: mysql, subquery, opencart

I have spent hours trying to get my query to run faster so far it works on my database.
however it takes 43 seconds to return my result. basically two tables are joined and I need to only return the latest **order_history_id** for each **order_id** with an **order_status** of 12.

I have tried using table shortcuts ie T1 T2 etc but to keep it simple my sql query has the relevant tables names below any help greatly appreciated

```
SELECT oc_order.order_id, oc_order.firstname, oc_order.lastname
   FROM oc_order 
      INNER JOIN oc_order_history ON oc_order.order_id = oc_order_history.order_id
         AND oc_order_history.comment NOT LIKE '' 
         AND oc_order_history.order_status_id LIKE '12'   
         AND order_history_id = (SELECT max(order_history_id) 
                                  FROM   oc_order_history i 
                                  WHERE  i.order_id = oc_order.order_id)
```

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` on each table in the query and post to the question so we can see your schema and indexes.  Also run `explain <your query>`  and post the results.

Comment: Hi Ray, its not allowing me to post the entire schema I have however found it on a picture [link](http://www.colab-aktiv.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/orders.jpg) I have tried to run `explain <my query>` but it gives error code 1064

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INNER JOIN` is little bit more resources eating as it adds another filtering condition, i.e. it is really a `LEFT JOIN` + `WHERE {joining column} IS NOT NULL`. Having indexes on columns taking part in joins and/or where clauses (especially string values that are searched with `LIKE`) will help to minimise the resources cost.

In Your query You are using `LIKE` in `WHERE` clause but completely wrong thus I can say You are misusing it. `LIKE` is used when You need to search for strings but You only know part of the string, e.g.

```
name LIKE 'Pet%'
```

will match all the rows with names like Pete, Peter, Petra, Petronela, Petriarca, Peter Pan, etc... If You want to search for exact value, compare with comparator signs `=`, `<>`, `<=`, `>=`, e.g.

```
name = 'Peter'
```

Now consider also this query:

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.firstname, o.lastname
FROM oc_order o
LEFT JOIN oc_order_history oh USING(order_id)
WHERE oh.order_status_id = 12   
    AND oh.order_history_id IN (
        SELECT MAX(order_history_id) 
        FROM oc_order_history
        GROUP BY order_history_id
    )
```

Comment: Hi Shadyyx thank you for your help, after changing the bottom line to GROUP BY order_id to filter out only the most recent items the query runs in just 8 seconds on my production database, hopefully after indexing this will be reduced down again. also thank you for explaining the uses.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `LIKE` if you do not want to search a text inside of a field.
Also the do not put the `WHERE` conditions into the `JOIN` conditions. 
In addition, check that you have **SQL Indexes** in the fields that you are joining and filtering on.

Update: after taking a look at your tables, I realised that `oc_order_history.comment` is a `Text` column, so search on this column is going to be very slow. If you try to remove the condition (like I did) I am sure your query it will be much faster. If you have to query for the comment column, try to change it to a VARCHAR or put and [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889827/indexing-a-mysql-text-column).

Also you should have indexes at least in `oc_order_history(order_status_id)` and in `oc_order_history(order_id)`

```
SELECT oc_order.order_id, oc_order.firstname, oc_order.lastname
FROM oc_order 
INNER JOIN oc_order_history ON oc_order.order_id = oc_order_history.order_id
WHERE oc_order_history.order_status_id = 12   
  AND order_history_id = (SELECT MAX(order_history_id) 
                          FROM oc_order_history i 
                          WHERE i.order_id = oc_order.order_id)
```

Comment: hi @Rafa thank you for your help, I have changed the query as you mentioned it definitely makes sense I am unfamiliar with <b>SQL Indexes</b> would adding an index to my frequently searched tables help a great deal? also worth noting the query now takes 84.5 seconds to complete that has to be a new record, is it possible to sort data before selecting it? Thank you

Comment: Hi Rafa, thank you for all your help, your query works beautifully on my test database, on the production one it is a little slower as soon as I can figure out the proper usage I will add the indexes as you mentioned. Thanks for all your help