# Mysql adding index for column type text does not improve performance while using select query

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am using InnoDB. From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889827/indexing-a-mysql-text-column), I found out that I have to specify the length if I want to add index to columns which type is TEXT.

But after successfully adding index, the performance for the select query stay the same. Anyone know why? I did check the index with show index from tableName and the index did exist.

So it was the last two table EventResultsFinalSummary and EventResultsPrelims.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ScheduleView AS
SELECT s.ScheduleID, e.EventRound, e.EventRoundsID, e.EventID, e.NumberCouplesInRound, n.NumberOnBack, eic.EventName AS 'Division',
       CONCAT(a1.FirstName, ' ', a1.LastName, ' - ', a2.FirstName, ' ', a2.LastName) AS 'Couple',
       s.SessionID AS 'Session', erfs.CouplePlace, c.CoupleID,
       s.Timeslot, s.SubFloor ,s.itemDuration,s.HeatNumber, o.ActivityName, st.StudioName AS 'DanceStudio', a.AgeName AS 'Age', s.competition_id, erp.CoupleVotes
FROM Schedule AS s
    LEFT JOIN EventRounds AS e ON s.EventRoundID = e.EventRoundsID AND s.competition_id = e.competition_id
    LEFT JOIN OtherActivities AS o ON s.OtherActivitiesID = o.OtherActivitiesID AND s.competition_id = o.competition_id
    LEFT JOIN EntriesEvents AS ee ON e.EventID = ee.EventID AND e.EventRound <= ee.EventRound AND e.Competition_id = ee.Competition_id
    LEFT JOIN Couples AS c ON ee.EntryID = c.CoupleID AND ee.Competition_id = c.Competition_id
    LEFT JOIN NumSysComps AS n ON c.CompetitorIDMan = n.CompetitorIDMan AND c.Competition_id = n.Competition_id
    LEFT JOIN Attendees AS a1 ON c.CompetitorIDMan = a1.AttendeeID AND c.Competition_id = a1.Competition_id
    LEFT JOIN Attendees AS a2 ON c.CompetitorIDLady = a2.AttendeeID AND c.Competition_id = a2.Competition_id
    LEFT JOIN Studios AS st ON a1.StudioID = st.StudioID AND a1.Competition_id = st.Competition_id
    LEFT JOIN EventsInComp AS eic ON eic.EventID = e.EventID AND eic.Competition_id = e.Competition_id
    LEFT JOIN ProAmSingleDanceEvents AS psd ON eic.ProAmSingleDanceEventID = psd.ProAmSingleDanceEventID AND eic.Competition_id = psd.Competition_id
    LEFT JOIN ProAmMultiDanceEvents AS pmd ON eic.ProAmMultiDanceEventID = pmd.ProAmMultiDanceEventID AND eic.Competition_id = pmd.Competition_id
    LEFT JOIN Ages AS a ON (
        psd.AgeID = a.AgeID AND psd.Competition_id = a.Competition_id
        OR
        pmd.AgeID = a.AgeID AND pmd.Competition_id = a.Competition_id
    )
    LEFT JOIN EventResultsFinalSummary AS erfs ON e.EventID = erfs.EventID AND c.CoupleID = erfs.CoupleID AND s.Competition_id = erfs.Competition_id
    LEFT JOIN EventResultsPrelims AS erp ON e.EventID = erp.EventID AND erp.EventRound = e.EventRound AND c.CoupleID = erp.CoupleID AND s.Competition_id = erp.Competition_id
    ORDER BY s.ScheduleID;
```

I added index to the column that I joined.
EventID, CoupleId, Competition_id for EventResultsFinalSummary and EventID, EventRound, Competition_id for EventResultsPrelims by using query like following.

My question is that when those columns have type like varchar or int, the select * query will only take 1s. But it take 26s when the type is Text.

```
ALTER TABLE `EventResultsPrelims` ADD INDEX(`EventID`(6));
```

Comment: Question about nothing. Place here your table structure, the index, the query you've tried.

Comment: It's a multiple join that includes 10 tables. The select query is just select * from the view that I create for the multiple join query.

Comment: And I have tried that if the column type is not TEXT but varchar or int, the performance did increase significantly after adding index.

Comment: Without details nobody would be able to answer.

Comment: The "execution plan" of the query is affected not only by a single index you may have added/improved but by the whole SQL statement. We cannot help you without seeing the actual query **and** the current execution plan. Please post both.

Comment: I edited my question to include more details.

Comment: What's the longest `EventID`?  I see that in about 4 tables; is it `TEXT` in all of them?  Do you have a prefixed index on all?