# Data Type for storing URLs

Tags: sql, database

What is the best data type to store URLs?

I need to save file system paths for pictures in a database.

Comment: Which database? The `VARCHAR` limitation may vary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best database field type for a URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219569/best-database-field-type-for-a-url)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best database field type for a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219569/best-database-field-type-for-a-url)

Answer (score 6):

URLs are strings and will be of variable lenghts.

If your database system supports this, use VARCHAR.

Answer (score 5):

VARCHAR is quite enough.

CHAR should be used for storing fix length character strings. String values will be space/blank padded before stored on disk. If this type is used to store varibale length strings, it will waste a lot of disk space.

Comment: CHAR should be used for storing fix length character strings. String values will be space/blank padded before stored on disk. If this type is used to store varibale length strings, it will waste a lot of disk space.

Answer (score 4):

VARCHAR2(4000) is sufficient for your needs

Answer (score 3):

We tend to save them as urlencoded `VARCHAR`s. (Since our URLs are coming to the database from a server, we encode them using PHP's `urlencode` and then decode them when we retrieve them with `urldecode`.) Don't think there's really much else that needs done - you could probably just store them as unencoded `VARCHAR`s.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, may i ask you WHY it is useful encode URLS in database?

Answer (score 2):

`varchar`.  Choose a suitable max length based on your domain knowledge.

Comment: sorry why varchar and not just char?

Comment: @GibboK: Because you would be wasting a lot of space using `char`. Unlike the fixed-size `char` data type, `varchar` does not store any blank characters when the full length of the field is not used.

Comment: Because char is fixed-length and you'd be wasting a lot of space.

Comment: varchar because the db can trim unused space, unless all your URLs are going to be the same length.

Comment: That's interesting - a downvote seven years later. I don't mind in the slightest (the StackOverflow novelty has long since worn off), but I'd be interested to learn if there's something new that means my answer is actively unhelpful.

Comment: varchar or nvarchar?

Comment: @Uzair_07 NVarChar is not necessary, because the limited acceptable characters in URIs means unicode isn't necessary. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2