# Default value for a text column

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my table having data type as `TEXT`.

How can I give it a default `NULL` value, so that when there is not entry in the column it doesn't consume memory.

I was reading a similar question on a forum where they said column should be allowed for null values; I did that but it doesn't work..

Comment: You can use triggers [*how to give Default Text like 'not updated' to text type in sql*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886364/how-to-give-default-text-like-not-updated-to-text-type-in-sql)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`TEXT` does not support default values of anything but `NULL`. As such, it's implicitly `DEFAULT NULL`, so you should not need to change anything.

Comment: so if there is no data in the column , will it save memory ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466872/why-cant-a-text-column-have-a-default-value-in-mysql

Comment: "For string types other than ENUM, the default value is the empty string" (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html)