# Mysql default value

Tags: mysql

I would like to know how to create a default value.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE something 
(
name varchar(20),
rank int
)
```

i would like to set the RANK value to 1.

(whenever i add new records, rank is automatically set to 1).

Comment: There are lots and lots of questions on this topic here at SO, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242990/default-value-for-a-text-column

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you set a default value for a MySQL Datetime column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE something 
(
    name varchar(20),
    rank int default 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the table already exists and you want to add the default value the fastest way to do it is with `ALTER TABLE` like this:

```
ALTER TABLE something
  ALTER COLUMN rank SET DEFAULT 1;
```