# Rails migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

This seems pretty straight forward but I'm not sure what is going wrong.

I'm attempting to do the following in my Rails migration:

```
change_column :foo, :bar, :text, :limit => 16777215
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Mysql::Error: BLOB/TEXT column 'bar' can't have a default value: ALTER TABLE `foo` CHANGE `bar` `email_contents` text(16777215) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
```

The only thing I can figure is causing an issue is that this change_column is occurring shortly after I added the column to foo and had to change it from type :string to type :text in the first place. These each come from their own migration scripts and look like this:

```
add_column :foo, :bar, :string, :null => false
```

and

```
change_column :foo, :bar, :text
```

As an experiment, I tried changing the first change_column (change_column :foo, :bar, :text) and discovered that this successfully alters the table. Unfortunately I cannot change either of the previous migrations and can only add new ones in our current implementation so that will not work in production. The question is, what is allowing me to change the column once but not twice?

**Update** Tried the first suggestion but got the following:

```
Mysql::Error: BLOB/TEXT column 'bar' can't have a default value: ALTER TABLE `foo` CHANGE `bar` `bar` text(16777215) DEFAULT ''
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try

`change_column :foo, :bar, :text, :limit => 16777215, :default => nil, :null => true`

Answer (score 3):

In case someone comes across this post and find this useful. I had the same problem the other way of avoid it is to change mysql configuration so that sql-mode is not strict, i.e. doesn't include `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` which it does by default.

Comment: more detailed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466872/why-cant-a-text-column-have-a-default-value-in-mysql

Comment: Is there any way to do that per database?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have other migrations where a `:limit` is specified with `:text` that work?

Possible that `:text` doesn't accept a `:limit`, and it simply maps to a specific MySQL datatype, if I read this correctly.

Map of Rails migration types, and MySQL data types:
http://www.orthogonalthought.com/blog/index.php/2007/06/mysql-and-ruby-on-rails-datatypes/

MySQL TEXT types (no mention of LIMIT, but doesn't rule it out I suppose:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html

Comment: Yes, in my posting where I mention my experiment what I missed was that the experiment was to change the old line to the one I'm trying to use in this new migration and it DOES work. They appear to not work in succession, however.

Answer (score 1):

For me this seems to be a result of going from MySQL 5.5.x to 5.6.x

*Note: Someone should go read [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](http://semver.org/)*

My fix was pretty simple...

#### WAS

```
change_column :my_table, :my_column, :mediumtext #=> Migrations Explosion
```

#### IS

```
change_column :my_table, :my_column, :mediumtext, default: nil #=> All good in the mysql 5.6.21
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
change_column :foo, :bar, :text, :limit => 16777215, :null => true
```

When `:null => false` is used (as in the old migration), Rails adds the DEFAULT bit to the ALTER TABLE statement. But, like the error says, TEXT columns can't have a DEFAULT. By changing it to `:null => true` in the new migration the problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    change_column :delayed_jobs, :handler, :text, 
      limit: 16777215, null: true, default: nil
```

I had to add `default: nil` and then Rails was OK setting `null: true`, which removes the default defined in an earlier migration.