# Change TEXT column default from null to '' (empty string)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where default value is not specified at the time of table creation. 
Now I want to change default value to '' (empty string).
When I run alter table query it get success but still on new row insertion table consider NULL as default value if column value is not specified.

TABLE Schema::

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `col1` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col2` TEXT,
  `col3` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col4` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

ALTER Query::

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` change `col2` `col2` text  default '';
```

Comment: CASE WHEN myColumn IS NULL THEN '' ELSE myColumn END

Comment: My Solution minimum change you structure of DB.

Comment: You should not apply default to col2, because its TEXT type  and it cannot be have DEFAULT.

Comment: @realnumber3012 - Unless I misunderstand you, that is part of a query; it won't change the column's DEFAULT value, as OP requests, so would need to be incorporated into ALL QUERIES that add a new row to the table!  Or you might be proposing it as part of a constraint that acts after any row change to the table, in which case a fully fleshed out answer is needed, to show how that would be done.

Answer (score 21):

Blob and text columns cannot have a `DEFAULT` value ([Ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html)). Depending on platform, MySQL may generate a warning or error when you try to do that.

Change the datatype to something more appropriate (e.g. `VARCHAR`).

Comment: You are right @Salman. Blob and text type cannot have default value.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - varchar's max length is no longer 255 with any of the newer versions of mysql.

Answer (score 2):

Use `modify`

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` MODIFY column `col2` text default '';
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all the Table schema is incorrect. It will throw error: 
Key column 'id' doesn't exist in table

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table1` (
  `col1` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col2` TEXT,
  `col3` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col4` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Correcting the question itself

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table1` (
  `col1` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col2` TEXT,
  `col3` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col4` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`col1`)
);
```

Now if you'll run the Alter statment

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` change `col2` `col2` text  default '';
```

The error message is: BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY or JSON column 'col2' can't have a `default` value. [Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html)

Good Read: [Why can't a text column have a default value in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466872/why-cant-a-text-column-have-a-default-value-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` change `col2` `col2` text  NOT NULL default '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable_name ALTER COLUMN columnname SET DEFAULT ' ' ;
```

Its working for me.Hope it will help you.

Comment: Won't let me edit my comment... I did this on varchar not text

Comment: This is string ' ' containing space. It's not empty.

Comment: you can .trim() it to make it an empty string. But yeah, that's not an empty string.

Comment: JDGuide: is it deliberate that you set the default value to a non-empty string (one space), even though that is not what was asked (nor is commonly done, IMHO)?  If that was accidental, please consider altering your answer. Until then, this is an incorrect answer to the question. Or needs explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In phpmyadmin go to "change" option for specific Field and select Default2 as As defined: and leave below text box empty

For example:

Field frequency
Type VARCHAR
Length/Values1 20
Default2 As defined: and Text box empty

Last click on Save button

Answer (score -1):

Alter table structure using the following query
`USE MODIFY ALTER TABLE <table> MODIFY <column> VARCHAR(<XX>) DEFAULT '';`