# Difference between VARCHAR and TEXT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, text, varchar

When we create a table in MySQL with a `VARCHAR` column, we have to set the length for it. But for `TEXT` type we don't have to provide the length.

What are the differences between `VARCHAR` and `TEXT`?

Answer (score 815, accepted):

### TL;DR

**`TEXT`**

- fixed max size of 65535 characters (you cannot limit the max size)
- takes 2 + `c` bytes of disk space, where `c` is the length of the stored string.
- cannot be (fully) part of an index. One would need to specify a prefix length.

**`VARCHAR(M)`**

- variable max size of `M` characters
- `M` needs to be between 1 and 65535
- takes 1 + `c` bytes (for `M` ≤ 255) or 2 + `c` (for 256 ≤ `M` ≤ 65535) bytes of disk space where `c` is the length of the stored string
- can be part of an index

### More Details

`TEXT` has a **fixed** max size of `2¹⁶-1 = 65535` characters.
`VARCHAR` has a **variable** max size `M` *up to* `M = 2¹⁶-1`.
So you cannot choose the size of `TEXT` but you can for a `VARCHAR`.

The other difference is, that you cannot put an index (except for a fulltext index) on a `TEXT` column.
So if you want to have an index on the column, you have to use `VARCHAR`. But notice that the length of an index is also limited, so if your `VARCHAR` column is too long you have to use only the first few characters of the `VARCHAR` column in your index (See the documentation for [`CREATE INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html)).

But you also want to use `VARCHAR`, if you know that the maximum length of the possible input string is only `M`, e.g. a phone number or a name or something like this. Then you can use `VARCHAR(30)` instead of `TINYTEXT` or `TEXT` and if someone tries to save the text of all three "Lord of the Ring" books in your phone number column you only store the first 30 characters :)

**Edit:** If the text you want to store in the database is longer than 65535 characters, you have to choose `MEDIUMTEXT` or `LONGTEXT`, but be careful: `MEDIUMTEXT` stores strings up to 16 MB, `LONGTEXT` up to 4 GB. If you use `LONGTEXT` and get the data via PHP (at least if you use `mysqli` without `store_result`), you maybe get a memory allocation error, because PHP tries to allocate 4 GB of memory to be sure the whole string can be buffered. This maybe also happens in other languages than PHP.

However, you should **always** check the input (Is it too long? Does it contain strange code?) *before* storing it in the database.

Notice: For both types, the required disk space depends only on the length of the stored string and not on the maximum length.
*E.g.* if you use the charset latin1 and store the text "Test" in `VARCHAR(30)`, `VARCHAR(100)` and `TINYTEXT`, it always requires 5 bytes (1 byte to store the length of the string and 1 byte for each character). If you store the same text in a `VARCHAR(2000)` or a `TEXT` column, it would also require the same space, but, in this case, it would be 6 bytes (2 bytes to store the string length and 1 byte for each character).

For more information have a look at the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html).

Finally, I want to add a notice, that both, `TEXT` and `VARCHAR` are variable length data types, and so they most likely minimize the space you need to store the data. But this comes with a trade-off for performance. If you need better performance, you have to use a fixed length type like `CHAR`. You can read more about this [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2643/46158).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's the difference between a "fixed max size" and a "variable max size"?

Comment: @DemiImp I'm not sure what I can add. What do you want to know?

Comment: @AbcAeffchen I believe I found out what you meant.  Basically a "fixed max size" means that you can't set the size at all - it's always 65535 even if you don't want to support a size that large.  Which means that TEXT is sort of  shorthand for a VARCHAR field with a max size of 2¹⁶-1, disregarding the indexing issue.  Did I understand right?

Comment: @DemiImp That is correct. I thought that this is what I wrote in the first two lines. I will add your explanation as a note.

Comment: What is the advantage of `TEXT` over `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2023513/3440545) and also notice the comments.

Comment: Exactly you can use prefix text column as index .  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-indexes.html

Comment: TEXT is 64K _bytes_ max, not _characters_.

Comment: No, the fixed length `CHAR` does not provide any noticeable performance improvement.  (This comes from an old wives tale about MyISAM tables; even there it was of dubious validity.)

Comment: Also, `TEXT` cannot have a default value whereas `VARCHAR` can. See [Why can't a text column have a default value in MySQL? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466872/why-cant-a-text-column-have-a-default-value-in-mysql)

Comment: When would you ever use `TEXT` over `VARCHAR`...same as @Solomon question, it's still not obvious to me?

Comment: I'm sticking to VARCHAR. Perhaps TEXT will one day be deprecated for SQL. Or perhaps not.  Came across this thread: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142424/sql-text-data-type-deprecated

Comment: TEXT does allow indexes (at least in current MySQL versions), but you have to specify an index prefix length ([see the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html)).

Comment: This is a really helpful answer - well written and clear.

Comment: @SolomonUcko You need to use TEXT when you want to create a table with two maximum-sized string columns, which means both of them may take 65535 characters. You cannot use two varchars with maximum size in a row at the same time because MySQL has limited the maximum row size, which is 65535. But you can use two TEXT in a row because TEXT only contributes 9 to 12 bytes toward the row size limit, TEXT's contents are stored separately from the rest of the row.

Comment: So, solely in terms of storage size, for `M > 255`, there's no advantage to `VARCHAR(M)`, over `TEXT`, correct? (They both consume 2 extra bytes plus the length of the string, right?)

Comment: Please note, that if VARCHAR column uses utf-8 collation (3 bytes per char) it can only have up to 21844 characters (65535/3 = 21844).

Comment: seems text can be indexed, you just need to specify a prefix: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-column-prefixes

Answer (score 108):

There is an important detail that has been omitted in the answer above.

MySQL imposes a limit of 65,535 bytes for the [max size of each row](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html#row-size-limits).
The size of a `VARCHAR` column is counted towards the maximum row size, while `TEXT` columns are assumed to be storing their data by reference so they only need 9-12 bytes. That means even if the "theoretical" max size of your `VARCHAR` field is 65,535 characters you won't be able to achieve that if you have more than one column in your table.

Also note that the actual number of bytes required by a `VARCHAR` field is dependent on the encoding of the column (and the content). MySQL counts the maximum possible bytes used toward the max row size, so if you use a multibyte encoding like `utf8mb4` ([which you almost certainly should](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30074553/385979)) it will use up even more of your maximum row size.

Correction: Regardless of how MySQL computes the max row size, whether or not the   `VARCHAR`/`TEXT` field data is ACTUALLY stored in the row or stored by reference depends on your underlying storage engine. For InnoDB the [row format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-row-format.html) affects this behavior. (Thanks Bill-Karwin)

Reasons to use `TEXT`:

- If you want to store a paragraph or more of text
- If you don't need to index the column
- If you have reached the row size limit for your table

Reasons to use `VARCHAR`:

- If you want to store a few words or a sentence
- If you want to index the (entire) column
- If you want to use the column with foreign-key constraints

Comment: No, both VARCHAR and TEXT store part of their content in the row by default. If the table's ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC *and* the content doesn't fit in the row, then  both VARCHAR or TEXT will be stored as a pointer to another page.

Comment: Also the statement about utf8mb4 taking more bytes is not accurate. Only if your content actually needs multi-byte characters, then those individual characters will take 2, 3, or 4 bytes. More common characters in utf8 still take 1 byte per character. This is the whole point of utf8!

Comment: If ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT, then both VARCHAR and TEXT will store their first 768 bytes with the row, and the remainder on another page.

Comment: The MySQL Manual [states](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html#row-size-limits) "... even if the storage engine is capable of supporting larger rows. BLOB and TEXT columns only contribute 9 to 12 bytes toward the row size limit because their contents are stored separately from the rest of the row." If it stores part of that content in the row that appears to contradict the manual. @BillKarwin

Comment: Also in the same page of the documentation it says "Storage for variable-length columns includes length bytes, which are counted toward the row size. For example, a VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 column takes two bytes to store the length of the value, so each value can take up to 767 bytes." I didn't mean that utf8mb4 always uses 4 bytes, just that MySQL counts it as such towards the max row size.

Comment: Okay, fair enough on the utf8mb4. I think that's accurate, VARCHAR counts toward the 64KB row size, but TEXT/BLOB don't. On the row storage, read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-row-format.html for more detail.

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify those details. Does that look accurate now? @BillKarwin

Comment: Yep! +1. FYI, this weird difference between the 64KB limit and the InnoDB row size limit is due to MySQL's storage engine architecture. As rows are transferred from the storage engine into the SQL layer, and then made into result sets, they have to satisfy different rules.

Comment: https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/understanding-strorage-sizes-for-mysql-text-data-types/

Comment: @code-commander, Please make a clarification on this sentence `That means even if the "theoretical" max size of your VARCHAR field is 65,535 characters, you won't be able to achieve that if you have more than one column in your table.`. Is this my statement correct? If I have 2 columns with max length = `65,535` . Each column will be able to take only half of its length or what?

Comment: @UtmostCreator MySQL will throw an error and not let you create / alter a table with two VARCHAR(65535) columns. It will say something like "Row size too large."