# MySQL Workbench TEXT() Column Parameter

Tags: mysql

I dont usually use MySQL workbench, I am trying to create a table with a text column by choosing TEXT(), however I am not sure what value I should put in between the '()'. If I leave it blank it gives me the error:

The given data type 
TEXT()
contains errors and cannot be accepted. The previous value is kept instead.

I can put a number inside the parentheses but I wanted to know how it affects the column.

I could not find any answers online. I know how it affects things such as DATETIME() but not this data type.

Answer (score 11):

In TEXT(M) M is an optional length. From [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html):

> An optional length M can be given for this type. If this is done,
>   MySQL creates the column as the smallest TEXT type large enough to
>   hold values M characters long.

So you can use it to specify the maximum number of characters you anticipate for the field.

If you omit the parens - just TEXT - it will default to 65,535. Otherwise, if you supply the parens and a value it will default to the appropriate text type (TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, LONGTEXT).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300821/difference-between-varchar-and-text-in-mysql) for a comparison with VARCHAR. One difference is that you cannot directly index a TEXT field, it requires a prefix.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was thinking about the data type wrong. I thought if we left it blank it would default to some value.

Comment: I've added a little more info to my answer.

Comment: Yes, you can index a text field, just you must use a prefix.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I've adjusted my answer.