# error when create mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
CREATE TABLE tblaccid2(
aAid TEXT(200) NOT NULL,
aEmail TEXT(88),
Password TEXT(32),
Status CHAR(5),
AccType CHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY(aAid)
)
```

> ```
>   #1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'aAid' used in key specification without a key length
> ```

pls give a example that can work with 1 or 2 primary key with 2 not primary key , primary key must be text or tinytext datatype

Comment: text type has no length attribute. besides this, setting a text as primary key is insane -))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL error: key specification without a key length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation on [MySQL Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-indexes.html):

> When you index a `BLOB` or `TEXT` column, you *must* specify a prefix length for the index.

So you need:

```
PRIMARY KEY (aAid(200))
```

However, there's little reason to be using `TEXT` for such short strings. Just change all your `TEXT` columns to `VARCHAR`. See [Difference between VARCHAR and TEXT in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300821/difference-between-varchar-and-text-in-mysql)