# MySQL varchar field selection and effect on buffer pool usage

Tags: mysql

As i have stored posttext as datatype varchar(5000) in post table.

1) So when i query posttext using below sql query in MySQL 5.6 Community version,

```
select posttext from post where postId = 1;
```

So does Whole posttext 5000 characters are stored in innodb buffer pool or innodb does not store this field value in buffer pool? because there are many posts in this table so if it stores whole value then innodb buffer pool might fill up early with uncertain unnecessary data.

2) Do i need to store it as text or varchar(5000) in terms of above question and in terms of performance?

Thanks,

Comment: It's better to use text for the posts.

Comment: @Shubhampokhriyal can you explain with respect to the question and advantages over it?

Comment: May be this link will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300821/difference-between-varchar-and-text-in-mysql