# In SQLite what is the maximum capacity of TEXT?

Tags: c#, sqlite

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25301046/4451521) TEXT has a maximum capacity of 65535 characters (or 64Kbytes). 
However I just build a test in which I stored a JSON string taken from a json file that is 305KBytes into t TEXT without problems

I am wondering if there is some property in TEXT that allows this

Comment: The default size for a default compiled version of SQLite is 1 billion bytes, 1,000,000,000. Note, **bytes**, not characters, so this depends on encoding. However, you need to call sqlite3_limit(...) to get the current actual limit.

Comment: Read https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html for details, but the maximum length you can configure it to use is  2147483647 bytes.

Comment: Also, that question you linked appears to be for MySQL, not sqlite.

Answer (score 3):

The limit, by default is 1 billion bytes rather than characters so the encoding has to be considered. However it can be changed.

The complete section regarding this is :-

> ## Maximum length of a string or BLOB
>
> The maximum number of bytes in a string or BLOB in SQLite is defined
> by the preprocessor macro SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH. The default value of this
> macro is 1 billion (1 thousand million or 1,000,000,000). You can
> raise or lower this value at compile-time using a command-line option
> like this:
>
> - *DSQLITE_MAX_LENGTH=123456789*
>
> The current implementation will only support a string or BLOB length up to 2 to the power of 31-1 or 2147483647. And some
> built-in functions such as hex() might fail well before that point. In
> security-sensitive applications it is best not to try to increase the
> maximum string and blob length. In fact, you might do well to lower
> the maximum string and blob length to something more in the range of a
> few million if that is possible.
>
> During part of SQLite's INSERT and SELECT processing, the complete
> content of each row in the database is encoded as a single BLOB. So
> the SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH parameter also determines the maximum number of
> bytes in a row.
>
> The maximum string or BLOB length can be lowered at run-time using the
> sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_LENGTH,size) interface.

[Limits In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)