# Mimic SQL table with ActiveModel Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, activemodel

I am using

```
ActiveModel::Model 
ActiveModel::Attributes.
```

I noticed that the attributes method used in my form object (active model) does not allow `:text` type.  I was wondering how I can setup attributes to mimic the below sql table?

```
create_table "teachers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "credentials", default: [], array: true
    t.integer "age"
    t.boolean "working", default: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_cpas_on_user_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `attribute :my_attribute, :string`.

There is no actual difference between how ActiveRecord treats casting `VARCHAR` columns (represented by the `:string` type) and `TEXT` columns.

The only difference is the SQL generated by the migration and thus what type of column is used for storing the actual information.

On Postgres for example both `TEXT` and `VARCHAR` columns have an upper limit of about 1GB, but `VARCHAR(n)` lets you set a lower arbitrary limit such as `VARCHAR(255)` - but there is no performance benefit to either and thus no advantage to using the TEXT type. This of course can vary depending on what RDBMS is in use.

See:

- [PostgreSQL: Difference between text and varchar (character varying)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848964/postgresql-difference-between-text-and-varchar-character-varying)
- [Difference between VARCHAR and TEXT in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300821/difference-between-varchar-and-text-in-mysql)

Comment: What about using array? Or setting a default value?

Comment: Use the array and default options. Read the manual...

Comment: Can you send the link, I looked for it, but could not find it the info for active model, I found array options for active record.