# error occured when create a table in mysql

Tags: mysql

going to create a data table in mysql using cli. I have following sql command,

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Customer(
    ->  id VARCHAR(20),
    ->  name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
    ->  dob DATE NULL,
    ->  gender INT NULL,
    ->  phone STRING,
    ->  mobile STRING,
    ->  nic STRING NULL,
    ->  country STRING,
    ->  address STRING,
    ->  region STRING,
    ->  city STRING,
    ->  state STRING,
    ->  postalcode STRING,
    ->  endorser1 STRING,
    ->  endorser2 STRING,
    ->  email STRING,
    ->  comment STRING,
    ->  image STRING,
    ->  type INT,
    ->  CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
```

but when I try to execute command got following error message

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'STRIN
G,
 mobile STRING,
 nic STRING NULL,
 country STRING,
 address STRING,
 reg' at line 6
mysql> ^A
```

how to fix this problem?

Comment: [There's no `STRING` type in mysql.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-type-syntax.html)

Comment: for one: STRING is not sql, that should be VARCHAR

Comment: @NicoHaase they're stuck at trying to create a table in mysql, because they are using invalid sql syntax

Comment: Well, yeah. Still, the OP could share what he has tried to resolve the problem

Comment: may I use varchar for string?

Comment: STRING is NOT a Reserved Word in MySQL.  Please see this URL - https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-varchar/ - for important information you need to be aware of.

Comment: @Ranawaka depends on your needs but take a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300821/difference-between-varchar-and-text-in-mysql) to make a more educated decision.