# MySql error message -Updating Tables: Database error: Invalid SQL: CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql

When installing script, I get this error message. Everything is configured as requested by the software. What could be the problem?

> Setup Database Tables Connection To DB: OK! Loading XML Data: OK! Removing Dead Tables: Done! Updating Tables: Database error: Invalid SQL:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE ads (
>     id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     title TEXT NOT NULL,
>     dsub TEXT NOT NULL,
>     username TEXT NOT NULL,
>     class CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
>     views INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     views_today INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     credits INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     target TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>     type INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     timed INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     pamount DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     pref VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
>     bgcolor VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '#FFFFFF',
>     forbid_retract INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     active INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
>     upgrade INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     new INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
>     daily_limit INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     country VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>     subtitle VARCHAR(167) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>     icon TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A',
>     subtitle_on INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     icon_on INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     oviews INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     oviews_today INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     targetban TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>     decline TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     hlimit INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     hlimit_views INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>     PRIMARY KEY (id),
>     KEY (class),
>     KEY (pref)
> )  ENGINE=INNODB;
> ```
>
> MySQL Error: 1101 (BLOB/TEXT column 'icon' can't have a default value) Session halted.

Comment: Are you in strict mode on Windows? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466872/why-cant-a-text-column-have-a-default-value-in-mysql

Comment: as the error message says: **MySQL Error: 1101 (BLOB/TEXT column 'icon' can't have a default value)**  remove it and the query will pass

Comment: Where to remove? Database not included BLOB/TEXT column.

Comment: As the error say, icon is a TEXT column. 
You have the line `icon TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A',`