# Sequelize migration - defining an empty JSON array

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

In my MySQL database i have a JSON column that i created using the following sequelize-cli migration:

```
queryInterface.addColumn(
          'Users',
          'favorites',
          {
              type: Sequelize.JSON,
              allowNull: false,
              defaultValue: []
  }
      );
```

However, instead of having a default value of `[]`, the records are getting a default value of `null` for that column.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try `defaultValue: '[]'`

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL - you cant have default value for JSON field in case of strict mode.

Here you can get some explanation and solution to resolve this issue:
[Why can't a text column have a default value in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466872/why-cant-a-text-column-have-a-default-value-in-mysql)

Then you can use your code without any modification.