# Laravel: give longText field a default value

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Pretty straightforward, in laravel I can't give longText or text fields a default value, given a field named "body" where body will probably have some text or html, how can I give it a default value in mysql?

Comment: I think it's not related to Laravel,
plz check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466872/why-cant-a-text-column-have-a-default-value-in-mysql

note that someone suggested to use trigger

Comment: you can set default values via Laravel on those fields, perhaps your DB has the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't a text column have a default value in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466872/why-cant-a-text-column-have-a-default-value-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, `mysql` has limitations around defaults and texts. Instead you can set it through code. Before anything is saved to the database, the `creating` event is triggered. You can hook into this and set the default value on the model using the boot function.

```
class YourModel
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->body = '<body></body>';
        });
    }
}
```

This can also be done through `observers`, which is a little more comprehensive. Avoids doing to much logic in the boot `method()`, which quickly can become crowded.