# MySQL datatype for URL's

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes, type-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best database field type for a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219569/best-database-field-type-for-a-url)

I am in the middle of transferring my access into mysql. My url's were datatype Anchor in the access database and I was wondering what would be the best datatype to store them in mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219569/best-database-field-type-for-a-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a generic VARCHAR(255)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/char.html

Answer (score 1):

I would just go with an appropriately sized `varchar`.