# Which SQL Data Type can accommodate links

Tags: mysql, sql

Which SQL data types can I use to accommodate links like `www.google.com`?

Which SQL data type can I use to store html codes?

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
```

I would like to store my links in the database, to use a for loop to automatically populate he links.

Comment: mostly `NVARCHAR(2083)` is enough, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219569/best-database-field-type-for-a-url)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any of the string data types (e.g. `varchar`, `nvarchar`, etc) can accomodate the `href` attributes from links. And another string column can accommodate the inner text. So something like:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    --Various columns
    LinkHref nvarchar(max) not null,
    LinkBody nvarchar(max) not null
)
```

Then, construct the surrounding anchor tag when you're extracting them for display. This also makes the links more searchable in the database in the future.

Comment: Actually you might want to further normalize, by splitting up the URI  into its components (protocol prefix [http, ftp,...], domain name, optional port, path). This would make queries like "give me all links to this domain" much easier.

Comment: but what if some of the hyperlinks contains more than one links? i cant seem to use the onclick function within a for loop