# Why 'unique = true' is not working in hibernate entity?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have created an entity with table name and column names. 
I have also added the uniquekey constraint for a column name. But when I run,  it shows the following error ;

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error
>   executing DDL "alter table ingredient add constraint
>   UK_co7ro6kyijhfik027h0y4d3n3 unique (ingredient_name).
>
> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Specified key was too long; max key
>   length is 1000 bytes

1. After I run the spring boot application, I have tried to add the unique constraint manually in MySQL workbench. - DOES NOT WORK
2. I have added the below code - DOES NOT WORK

```
    @Table(name = "ingredient", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(name="uk_ingredient_name",columnNames="ingredient_name"))

    @Column(name = "ingredient_name" ,unique = true)
    private String ingredientName;
```

3. Tried to create a table manually in Mysql workbench and tried to alter the column name with unique key later. THIS WORKS. But I want hibernate to do this for me.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ingredient")
    public class Ingredient {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ingredient_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "ingredient_name" ,unique = true)
    private String ingredientName;
```

I want to save the ingredients without any repetitions. I do not want duplicate entries.
I have gone through other answers and none of those solutions helped me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746207/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes)

Comment: Please do a search before - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746207/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes . Just limit the length of ingredientName field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: #1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes - mysql 5.0.91](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642429/error-1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes-mysql)

Comment: I have gone through other answers and none of those solutions helped me. They have given solutions for MySQL which I didn't require.  I finally figured it was because of the length attribute in @Column. This solution is not present in any of the questions which you have sent.

Answer (score 1):

Could you remove

```
,unique = true
```

from @Column annotation and try, it seems there is an hibernate bug .When using unique true it does not obey the naming strategy.

For more information look at this post

[@UniqueConstraint and @Column(unique = true) in hibernate annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372654/uniqueconstraint-and-columnunique-true-in-hibernate-annotation)

and this one

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11586

After removing the unique=true I am able to generate the unique constraint with the specified name that is 'uk_ingredient_name'.Since it is already specified in the @Table annotation.

The error you are getting is because hibernate is generating a unique constraint name which is hitting the allowed limit and it is not taking into the account the constraint name you have declared.

Comment: Thank you, but this did not help. I had already tried this way , that is, removing unique = true . I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding length = 20 in the @column. 
It works completely fine without any error.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column(name="username", length=8, unique=true)
```

worked fine for me.