# Data type for a large text field?

Tags: mysql

I need to store a URL string in my database, the string is quite long (the length differs per row but it will be at least 500 characters).

What data type is best suited, varchar/text/medium text/long text?

Comment: Which version of MySQL? If it's at least 5.0.3, then a VARCHAR can hold 65,535 characters.

Comment: How would I specify that many chars?

Comment: You might want to give [Best database field type for a URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219569/best-database-field-type-for-a-url) a read; basically, you'd just do `VARCHAR(2083)`